# How do I describe mutually exclusive values of properties?

Tags: jsonschema

I have two properties (propOne and propTwo).

If one of the properties values is true the other must be set to false.

How do I describe this in jsonschema?

I can say if propOne is true require propTwo, but this isn't enough:

```
"anyOf": [
    {
        "not": {
            "properties": {
                "propOne": {
                    "const": true
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "propOne"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "required": [
            "propTwo"
        ]
    }
],
```

What is the most concise way to describe my requirements?

Edit:
Per the answer this does what I want. I know there is a handful of ways to describe this. It seems like oneOf is the most concise? I think if conditions would require more lines?

```
"oneOf": [
    {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "propOne": {
                "const": true
            },
            "propTwo": {
                "const": false
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "propOne": {
                "const": true
            },
            "propTwo": {
                "const": false
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the if/then/else keywords, and also oneOf (see https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html)

So, in pseudocode:

- must be an object.
- require propOne and propTwo.
- propOne is a boolean.
- propTwo is a boolean.

and either of these are equivalent (when combined with the above restrictions):

- if propOne is true, then propTwo is false, else propTrue is true.
- oneOf:

  - propOne is true and propTwo is false.
  - propOne is false and propTwo is true.

Comment: Is the `description` field supported for oneOf, anyOf, and if conditions? I generate markdown from json schema and annotating these configs would be useful

Comment: It would vary according to whatever tool you are using. Try it and see!

Comment: Oh I just wanted to know if it was allowed in the json schema protocol (regardless of tool support), but sounds like it is?